# I didn't post for 11 days and can't post anything right now

Tags: bug

I just have a question to ask and the question editor says that I cannot post anything new for 90 minutes, even if my latest post is dated March 21st, 2017. Is this a bug?

Or just a restriction (even if I don't think so)?